# Perl: Trim multi-line records

Tags: perl

I need to read in multi-line records and trim them down to exactly 40 lines. Then
pad them to be 45 lines. They might be as large as 70 + lines. These records need
to end up being 45 lines.

The record separator is a line beginning with the pattern /^#matchee/.

I'm assuming you'd set $/ to #matchee.

```
{
    $/ = "#matchee";

    while (<>) {
        # I need to print first 40
        # lines of each record then
        # pad to 45 with delimiter as
        # last line.
    }
}
```

Sample record

```
REDUNDANCY DEPARTMENT
Anonymous Ave

Item 1
Item 2



<bunch of blank lines>
#matchee
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution...

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

{
    $/ = "#matchee";

    while (my @line = split "\n", <> ) {

    # print first 40 lines of record
        for my $counter (0..39) {
             print($line[$counter] . "\n");
        }

        # pad record with four extra blank lines
        # (last record already ends with a newline)
        print "\n" x 4;
    }
}
```

+1 for using `$/ = "#matchee";`

This isn't quite right... the first record has 45 lines, the second has 44.

Comment: `for my $counter (0..39) { ... }`

Comment: If using a later version of Perl, you can do `say "...";` instead of `print "...\n";`, though, I'm not entirely sure if you set the line termination variable.  Also it should be `#!/usr/bin/...` (no space)

Comment: Thanks for the hint on `say "..."`. I've been stuck in perl 5.8.8 at work for the last few years. We're going to be moving to SLES 11 (which uses perl 5.10) real soon now. -- In terms of the space after the shebang ... I've always used it. A little googling shows that #! isn't defined by POSIX... it's a convention implemented by all modern Unices, and they all seem to accept but not require a space after the shebang.

Comment: I think that's because the OS will try to determine the file type and then the associated program by default.  In other words, the line hardly ever comes into play because you're using the default Perl installed on the system.  If, however, you have multiple versions of Perl, and you want to use the alternative - I think that's when it really matters in Linux.  Instead of using the one you think you specified, it'll use the default (which tends to be the older version).  It's been a while, so I could be wrong on this, but I think that's what I've seen in the past.

Comment: Yeah, the only other thing with that `print` statement is that you should be consistent - you don't *need* the parentheses.  In fact, since you're already interpolating I think you could also do `print "$line[$counter]\n";`

Comment: I guess final comment is you don't even need a `for` loop.  This is a good place where an array slice would be useful.  `print join("\n", @line[0..39]);` --- and --- it will always output *44* lines because you're printing 40 in the loop and then you're only printing 4 blank ones after the loop.  To get 45, you'd have to do `x 5` at the end there.

Comment: Wow. I didn't know you could use a range inside the array subscript like that. I'll have to play around with that.

Comment: You should be able to, but I forgot the trailing `. "\n"` after the join, for the last element

Answer (score 1):

You specify that "The record separator is a line beginning with the pattern /^#matchee/". This somewhat complicates the record separation as `$/` is [a special string, but not a regex](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%2f). You didn't specify if your output is using the same record separator, but I assume so. Here's an approach that seems to work.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub take_and_pad_lines {
  my ($str, $take, $pad) = @_;

  my @lines = (split(/\n/, $str))[0..$take-1];
  return join "\n", @lines, ('') x ($pad - $take);
}


{
  $/ = "#matchee";

  while (my $record = <> ) {
    # because RS is really begins-with we must clean up first line
    # and double check last record
    unless (1 == $.) {
      $record =~ s/\A.*\n//m;
      last if eof() && $record eq '';
    }

    print take_and_pad_lines( $record, 40, 45 ), "\n";
    print "$/\n" unless eof();
  }
}
```

Comment: Aha. That explains why I was getting differing number of line feeds contained in the the first and second records... the first record didn't start with the delimiter, and was therefore one line shorter than the rest.